# Form redirects after create in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the tutorial on railstutorial.org but with modifications. There is a form where I want to create users. But when i create users, it redirects me to the user page. How can I edit it? I want it to remain on the same page with a flash notification stating that the person has already been created. Below is the create function I currently have.

```
  def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save

      flash.now[:success] = "User Added!"

      render 'new'

    else

      render 'new'

    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect_to new_user_path, notice: 'New User Added'
```

Or check your routes, and see which page you want to redirect, in console type:

```
rake routes
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..try `redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User Added'`